# How to use neovim lsp keybindings?

Tags: neovim

I have neovim 0.6.1 configured with some LSPs and using the default configurations found here: https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig#suggested-configuration. Some of the key bindings such as `vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, 'n', '<space>rn', '<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.rename()<CR>', opts)` are not working.

The `vim.lsp.buf.rename()` command works correctly if I call it manually like `:lua vim.lsp.buf.rename()`.

If I do `:noremap <space>rn :lua vim.lsp.buf.rename()<CR>` during a session the rename keybinding works correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default config from nvim-cmp was also calling setup{} which effectively cleared the on_attach callback required to enable the lsp keybindings.